# How do I select a default value for my select (dropdown) in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a useEffect to make some API calls on loading the page. Now I store the data I get using useState and display it using a select. I also have a useState to hold the selected value of the dropdown.

```
const [companies, setCompanies] = useState([]);
//Selected company to create job for, with the first one as default
const [selectedCompanyId, setSelectedCompanyId] = useState('');

const getCompanies = async () => {
    const response = await getMyCompanies();
    
    if(response.data.status === 200)
    {            
        if(response.data.companies.length === 0)
        {
            setNoCompanyFound(true);
        }
        else
        {
            setCompanies(response.data.companies); 
            setNoCompanyFound(false);                                          
        }                                         
    }
}

<select onChange={handleChangeCompany}>
     {companies.map(company => (
           <option value={company.id}>
                  {company.name}
           </option>
      ))}
 </select>

 const handleChangeCompany = (event) => {
    setSelectedCompanyId(event.target.value);        
  };
```

If the user wants the first option I need to have a default set in the useState, so I can send that value to the API. I tried setting a default the following way:

```
//Selected company to create job for, with the first one as default
const [selectedCompanyId, setSelectedCompanyId] = useState(companies[0].id);
```

Sadly when this is being set the useState hook is not done yet and the value is undefined. Setting it in the useEffect with setSelectedCompanyId() also gives undefined.
Could some one help me with how I can properly initialize a default value for the select?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value on the select directly:

```
<select onChange={handleChangeCompany} defaultValue={companies[0].id}>
     {companies.map(company => (
           <option value={company.id}>
                  {company.name}
           </option>
      ))}
 </select>
```

Alternatively, wait for the company data to load before displaying the select:

```
{
  companies.length && (
    <select onChange={handleChangeCompany}>
      {companies.map((company) => (
        <option value={company.id}>{company.name}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to have a default value in the useState for my code to send the right id to the API: `const [selectedCompanyId, setSelectedCompanyId] = useState('');` I dont see how this defaultValue can help me with that. defaultValue does not call onChange right?

Comment: Update my answer. You can also set `loading` state value if you want more granular control over the loading state.

Comment: I think I did not explain my question clear enough, sorry